# Implement QR code scanner in phonegap app with visual studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am building an app using Phonegap in visual studio 2013 , I try to use this plugin of QR code reader: 
https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/.
I am using 
 [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com/) to build my application.

So far it doesn't work and the app doesn't recognize it.
How can I implement a QR-Code Scanner in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using build.phonegap.com, you need to use their version of the plugins.

See https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/261

You can use this plugin by editing you config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="1.1.0" />
```